# stores locator on google map v3 doesn't work well when search a place

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm working on store locator using google maps api v3. but there was an error occurred when I searched "new orleans", "mexico", and any places that have not the stores data.

Here is the link to the course:

[create a store locator using PHP/MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

Can anyone help me out to correct the code, make it center to the place I input in the "addressInput", even if there is no data in that location?

I suspect that it was some code missing after we load the search results, but I cannot find it out.

Answer (score 0):

look at the article here  http://technico.qnownow.com/create-a-store-locator-with-google-maps/
it is similar but it plots the typed in address first, then searches for stores near by.

Comment: Thx, Vanamali! I've fixed it up. And the link u gave me uses "jason" to extract the results instead of the xml. Do u know the diff? 

And one more quiz: can I use getBounds() to detect the bounds of the current map so that instantly display the stores according to the map? Many thx!